# filtering with statement without using from

Tags: sql, oracle, count, where-clause

I want to count products showed in events between two dates. I have to fill 9 columns, each with other product type.

I would like to ask you if there are possibility to short this statement.
Below sql is first working but not effective attempt.

```
with events(event_id, customer_id) as (
     select * from event
     where start_date >= :stare_date
     and end_date <= :end_date
),
select 
 (select count(*) from event_product where event_id in (select event_id from events where customer_id = customer.customer_id) and product_type = 'YLW') customer_ylw_products -- it works but its ugly and non effective
 -------
 -- repeat seven times for other type of products
 -------
 (select count(*) from event_product where event_id in (select event_id from events where customer_id = customer.customer_id) and product_type = 'RTL') customer_rtl_products
from customer
;
```

Notice that line

```
(select event_id from events where customer_id = customer.customer_id)
```

repeats about 9 times.

I've been trying to short this one by add following:

```
with events(event_id, customer_id) as (
     select * from event
     where start_date >= :stare_date
     and end_date <= :end_date
),
**customer_events (event_id, customer_id) as (select * from events)**
select
(select count(*) from event_product where event_id in (select event_id from customer_events) and product_type = 'RTL') customer_rtl_products
from customers
where customer_events.customer_id = customer.customer_id -- doesnt works
having customer_events.customer_id = customer.customer_id -- doesnt works
```

Comment: with mssqlserver you could write with transact-sql parametrized stored procedures or functions. i guess other dbms have similar functions.

Comment: @Dimt: This is Oracle

Comment: @user2504380: I have to do it without it. Functions and procedures would make it so simple

Comment: @WhereIsYourGod you could try sqlfiddle to let people play and try some solutions for you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use case expressions?

```
WITH
      events (event_id, customer_id)
      AS (
                  SELECT
                        *
                  FROM event
                  WHERE start_date >= :stare_date
                        AND end_date <= :end_date
            )
SELECT
      *
FROM customer
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        event_product.customer_id
                      , COUNT(CASE
                              WHEN event_product.product_type = 'YLW' THEN 1 END) AS count_YLW
                      , COUNT(CASE
                              WHEN event_product.product_type = 'RTL' THEN 1 END) AS count_RTL
                  FROM event_product
                        INNER JOIN events
                                    ON event_product.event_id = events.event_id
                  GROUP BY
                        event_product.customer_id
            ) ev_counts
                  ON customer.customer_id = ev_counts.customer_id
;
```

You could do this without the CTE too if you prefer, just use what you currently have in the CTE as a derived table where `events` is now placed in the inner join.

---

footnote `select *` is a convenience only I don't know what fields are to be used, but they should be specified.

Answer (score 1):

@Used_By_Already thanks for inspire me with inner joins between event_product and event and that Event_product doesnt have column customer_id so I simply added it!

That's my solution

```
with events(event_id, customer_id) as (
  select * from event
  where start_date >= :stare_date
  and end_date <= :end_date
),
product_events (customer_id, product_type) as (
  select event.customer_id, event_product.product_type 
  from events,event_product
  where event_product.event_id = event.event_id and event_product.product_type in (''product_types'')
)
select
  (select count(*) from product_events where customer_id = customer.customer_id and product_type = 'RTL') customer_rtl_products
from customers;
```

Performance for 50 rows in search increased from 45 seconds to only 5!

Thank you so much!